format SQL SP result into json fomat in Spring Boot
I am getting data from SQL Stored Procedural and I want to manipulate on that data as array of json objects, In laravel it is simple and straight because the result is in the collection of object, but in spring boot the result is as seen as below inside result-set. where by from my result "message" and "code" are the keys in the retuned object.
{#result-set-1=[{message=Credited Amount: 1.000 , On Card: 000 0040,By: Gab R, code=200}]}

Where by

"Credited Amount: 1.000 , On Card: 000 0040,By: Gab R"

is one string in key message and code value 200 is integer
I have tried to add some regrex manipulation as seen below without a success,
    private String preprocessResponse(String response) {
    // Check if the response starts with the prefix and ends with the suffix
    String prefix = "{#result-set-1=";
    String suffix = "]}";

    if (response.startsWith(prefix) && response.endsWith(suffix)) {
        // Remove the prefix and suffix
        response = response.substring(prefix.length(), response.length() - 1);
    }

    // Regular expressions to properly handle key-value pairs and quote the values correctly
    response = response.replaceAll("(\\w+)=([^,\\]\\[]+)", "\"$1\":\"$2\"")
            .replaceAll("\"(\\d+)\"", "$1"); // Remove quotes around numbers

    // Fix incorrectly formatted JSON structures (e.g., unclosed quotes, brackets)
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"response_code\":\"(\\d+)}\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);
    response = matcher.replaceAll("\"response_code\":$1}");

    // Ensure the response ends with the proper JSON array closing bracket
    if (!response.endsWith("]")) {
        response += "]";
    }

    return response;
}

what is the proper way to handle SQL SP result?

If you have SQL Server 2016 or later, you can return JSON directly from the database in that stored procedure

@YitzhakKhabinsky are refering the use of  FOR JSON PATH, if that the case it does not work, I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM).  Istill receive the same result {#result-set-1=[{message=Credited Amount: 1.000 , On Card: 000 0040,By: Gab R, code=200}]}.
SQL SP  SELECT @ResponseMessage as message, 200 as response_code FOR JSON PATH

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
